# Error with installing FFI and Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, react-native

When I run `npx react-native projectname`, the project is only created partially.

Now when I run `bundle install` I get:

`1. Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`2. An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that "gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'" succeeds before bundling.`

[image]

Yes, I have installed the ffi 1.15.5 (below screenshot) but it is still saying I dont have it

[image]

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]

**pod** --version: 1.11.3

I am impressed how difficult it is to start a project. Someone please help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? we just upgraded and I'm having the same issue.